# "Use product rule" in derivation?

Tags: calculus

I have a derivation of a law of motion for a variable in an economics class. In the derivation, there is a step:

Use the product rule, therefore, $\frac{\dot{xy}}{xy}=\frac{\dot{x}}{x}+\frac{\dot{y}}{y}$

I feel like I learned this in high school, but forgot why this works.

Comment: $\frac{1}{xy}\frac{d}{dt}xy=\frac{1}{xy}\left(y\frac{d}{dt}x+x\frac{d}{dt}y\right)$

Comment: What you’ve written is just wrong. You mean $(xy)^\cdot$? Now do product rule.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks @Ted. That's why I've been having trouble.

Comment: Don't waste time with product rule, quotient rule , etc etc . Just learn the derivative of composite function relates to two  functions and then you can just derive all those waste of time to remember rules and know why they are what they are

Comment: @jimjim Remembering things by heart is the opposite of wasting time, though: you spend twenty minutes one day, then you save one minute every other time.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path : interesting take, it is true if one is to do repetitive  mundane tasks, comes handy for reciting poetry etc. but in 21st century thinking we have machines for those types of tasks.

Comment: @jimjim There is some merit to being able to do computations on your own, without them necessarily being repetitive. I won't go into the details because I can see that you are rather (aggressively) opinionated on that matter, and that would make for a rather dull discussion.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path : Thank you for the observation, I had enough of aggressive low lives that pushed for the idea of being a memory monkey, I am not here to discuss my preferences vs others, I only stated my approach and it was not me who pushed for the alternative on to you, there is plenty of push being maid for being a memory monkey by the all the education systems all over the world, so there is nothing new about the merits of it that can be added to. The ability to deduce all the trivial side notes from as few as possible principles is ultimate goal in most scientific disciplines though.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path : if there is way to test one idea against the other I am all in, no way a discussion with someone like you would be dull, but a concrete example that we can demonstrate the ideas would be educational for others :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has:
$$\frac{x'}{x}+\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{x'y}{xy} + \frac{xy'}{xy} = \frac{x' y+x y'}{xy} = \frac{(xy)'}{xy}$$
using the fact that $(xy)'=x'y+xy'$ (product rule).